# Ormlite date format ignored on Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, simpledateformat, ormlite

I need to store date types with a specific format in Android application. I use Ormlite for persistence, so I have configured as follows:

```
 @DatabaseField(columnName = DATE_OF_BIRTH, canBeNull = true, useGetSet = true,
        dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = ApplicationConstants.DATE_FORMAT)
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

where ApplicationConstants.DATE_FORMAT is 'yyyy-MM-dd'. I have tried different formats but still no luck. When I read the field it is formatted like this: 'Sat Oct 01 00:00:00 EET 1988'. I even tried using the Sqlite formats specified in [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). I think the issue is the difference between the SimpleDateFormat formats and Sqlite formats. I am not sure. Maybe I am missing something.Thanks

Comment: Your Date type of field is from namespace java.util or java.sql?

Comment: It is java.util.Date field

Comment: After researching I found that it stores the date in the right format but when it reads it back is wrong. So for example using the format "dd-MM-yyyy" it will store the date 31 august 1988 like this: 31-08-1988 but when the application retrieves it is in this format: Wed Aug 31 00:00:00 EEST 1988